# Load Balancer with Healt Check for JBoss 7.1 or Apache

Tags: java, apache, jboss7.x, load-balancing, high-availability

I need to set up a high availability solution for 2 servers **JBoss 7.1** or **Apache**, I read the documentation and I find `mod_cluster` and `ajp` but they don't have health check.

Need to assemble a solution with 2 servers JBoss and 2 load balancers.

Which solution for Load Balancer you recommend to me?

Comment: As of 1.1.0, mod_cluster’s HA singleton master leverages the `PING` command to detect validate the health of a leaving member before determining that the worker and its contexts should be removed.  If the ping was unsuccessful this send a `REMOVE-APP *` command to the proxy on behalf of the crashed member.  If the ping was successful, then the proxy can still communicate with the node, and removing it would be inappropriate, thus we leave it alone.

Comment: Have you considered putting [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html#nginx_load_balancing_health_checks) in front of your servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is mod_cluster. Currently [1.3.1.Final](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/ModclusterVersion131FinalReleased).

- loadbalancing with load calculated on the worker nodes
- High-Availablity in conjunction with worker clustering
- before the worker is contacted, either AJP cping/cpong logic takes place or OPTIONS method is sent (in case of HTTP(S)) in order to assert worker's availability
- seamless failover
- sticky sessions fine tuning
- one worker could be connected to more balancers
- workers configure available application contexts with the Apache load balancer automatically via a special set of configuration messages